# Cakephp 2 ACL ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

I am trying to implement the ACL tutorial found here: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I followed all the instructions, however when I try to go to **[my_site]/users/add**  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

I found this on the Cakephp website:

> This happens when for example we have an element that receives data
>   from a method of a controller, and the implementation of this method
>   requires conducting the login would create an infinite loop that
>   eventually will cause the browser to decline redirects

And they suggest this as the fix:

```
function  beforeFilter ()  { 
 $ this -> Auth -> allow ( 'CONTROLLER_NAME' ); 
}
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

If I change the AppController from this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'login', 'add');
}
```

to:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}
```

I dont get the error anymore but get redirected to **[my_site]/users/login**

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong that I can't view the User-Add page?
TIA!

UserController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
    }
```

Login function (UsersController):

```
Public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

Auth Component Loader:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')
        )
    );
```

Comment: Show us your UserController `beforeFilter` method please.

Comment: Edited and added my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem with help Brian:

> Do you have an requestAction() code? If so, try adding this in

```
AppController::beforeFilter() 

if (isset($this->params['requested'])) $this->Auth->allow($this->action);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with ACL, but with the Auth component denying access to your `UsersController` add and login functions, to which it is trying to redirect the user. Make sure the `add` and `login` functions are public, by adding this line in your `UsersController` (rather than your `AppController`):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('add', 'login'));
}
```

The loop you are now encountering is because the add and login functions are not public and therefor the loop looks like: `add -> Unauthorized -> login -> Unauthorized -> login` ... and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the UsersController with the code you supplied but still getting the same result :(

Comment: @Ronnyvdb If you happen to use Chrome as a browser, press F12 to open the console, go to the Network tab and then open the page you want to access. It should clarify exactly where the loop is going to all the time. Apparently it's not the login function, but something else.

Comment: this is the screen shot of the console: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2fuwuFx5KppVG9WeXVCZE5kYnM/edit

Comment: heres something interesting... I changed my login function in the UsersController to just echo "test"; and I didnt get the redirect error, i edited my question and added the login function, any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your component "constructor" look like? Can you add the code that loads the `AuthComponent` (from your `AppController` or `UsersController`) to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `beforeFilter()`'s `Auth->allow('_CONTROLLER_NAME')` to:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Hope that works for you!