# How to bypass ACL queries on requestAction in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, view, acl, cakephp-2.4

Showing recents posts in an element by requestAction method is great, but it causes redundant queries if ACL is used. Is there a way to disable those?

Note: My version of CakePHP is 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you, but after 2 days of Googling I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592940

Put the following code in:

> AppController::beforeFilter()
>
> if (isset($this->params['requested']))
>   $this->Auth->allow($this->action);